# Eclipse maven compiler not supporting compiler-plugin compilerArgs

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-module, maven-compiler-plugin

We have a collection of Java module projects (using JDK11).

There is a separate project for our integration tests. This project needs to be able to access the main application project to run its tests, but we don't want to add an export to the main application module because it's only needed when we're running our tests.

The solution has been to add the export using *compilerArgs* in our integration test project:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>${java.version}</release>
                <parameters>true</parameters>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--add-exports</arg>
                    <arg>com.example.application/com.example.application=com.example.integration_tests</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This works for a command line `mvn clean install`. But sadly it doesn't work for eclipse.
For whatever reason eclipse ignores these compilerArgs and keeps giving errors that the main application class is not accessible.

Is there some way to force eclipse to use these compilerArgs? Or is this some aspect of the module system that Eclipse hasn't gotten around to covering yet?

Answer (score 3):

The `--add-exports` compiler argument **can be set manually** for Maven dependencies **in the `.classpath` file by replacing**

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

with

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="add-exports" value="com.example.application/com.example.application=com.example.integration_tests"/>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Unfortunately, **right-clicking the project** and choosing ***Maven > Update Project...* reverses the manual settings** if the option ***Update project configuration from pom.xml*** is selected (which is by default).

See: [**Eclipse bug 543631 - Eclipse - Maven - JPMS**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=543631) (please comment and vote there if you would like to have this feature)

To restore your manual settings after updating the project, you can replace the `.classpath` file with its version before updating the project.

Please consider the following alternatives to a separate project for test code that uses JPMS but accesses internal stuff of a module:

- Put the test code into `src/test/java/` instead of into a separate project (accessing internals indicates that it is an unit test rather than an integration test)
- In the separate (integration) test project do not access interal stuff of required module
- Do not use JPMS in the separate (integration) test project

Comment: The manual way only seems to work for modules inside the JRE. In this case it's another module which was made by myself. The specific "Is modular" of the dependency is non modifiable and the module can't be found in the add exports dialog of either the JRE System library or the general maven dependencies.

Thanks for the Eclipse bug link though. Hopefully this will be adressed.

Comment: @SvenT23 Editing the `.classpath` file works for me (see my edited answer). If you want this feature request to be addressed, you should not call it _error_ or say that you are _very frustrated_. As an open source developer, you'd rather spend your time making happy people happier than frustrated people less frustrated. You should also show that it is important to you by creating an example to reproduce the issue and taking some time looking into the code (and maybe proposing a solution). Two-thirds of about 80 bugs I reported to Eclipse have already been fixed that way.

Comment: I said it was very frustrating to see errors because that's what eclipse is showing, an error. You're probably right about the frustrated part though, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The `<compilerArgs>` element requires that `<fork>true</fork>`, which is missing from the Maven pom excerpt in the question.  See the [maven-compiler-plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html).